# How to make http call with file in groovy to upload a file and build arguments

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I can make [jenkins remote api request](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to pass a file and do some thing with it using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

```
 curl http://server.com:8080/job/dummyJob/build -F file0=@/tmp/data  -F json='{"parameter": [{"name":"LIST","file":"file0"}, {"name":"SEARCH", "value":"Build"}, {"name":"LABEL", "value":"2015/11/20"}, {"name":"UPDATEDB", "value":"TRUE"}  ]}'
```

What will be groovy way of doing this? (java-ish code below)

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab(group = 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module = 'httpclient', version = '4.5.1'), 
         @Grab(group = 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module = 'httpmime', version = '4.5.1') 
])

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);


HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.com:8080/job/dummyJob/build");

//need multipart ofrm submission
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)


String payLoad = '''{"parameter": [{"name":"LIST","file":"file0"}, {"name":"SEARCH", "value":"Build"}, {"name":"LABEL", "value":"2015/11/20"}, {"name":"UPDATEDB", "value":"TRUE"}  ]}'''
File file = new File("c:/payload.txt");



ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "text/txt");
ContentBody json = new StringBody(payLoad)


builder.addPart(new FormBodyPart("file0", cbFile)) //file0 is the name used in json data structure
builder.addPart(new FormBodyPart("json", json)) //all of the json content with name json


httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, let me know if there are any problems:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'),
    @Grab('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1')
])

String jsonText ='''{"parameter": [{"name":"LIST","file":"file0"}, {"name":"SEARCH", "value":"Build"}, {"name":"LABEL", "value":"2015/11/20"}, {"name":"UPDATEDB", "value":"TRUE"}  ]}'''
File file = new File("c:/payload.txt");

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://server.com:8080')

http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.TEXT) {req->
    uri.path = '/job/dummyJob/build'

    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartRequestEntity = new MultipartEntityBuilder()
    multipartRequestEntity.addPart('file0', new FileBody(file, "text/txt"))
    multipartRequestEntity.addPart('json', new StringBody(jsonText))

    req .entity =  multipartRequestEntity.build()

    response.success = { resp, data ->
        // response text
        println data.getText()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got some exceptions.. Fixed with some changes. Essentially added setEntity call.    addPart needed StringBody as well. I am editing the answer. please review.

Comment: Í'm trying to do somethings like t his from a Jenkins pipeline. I just paster the above suggested code directly into my Jenkins pipeline, but I run into the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab