# Run Jenkins Job Through JAVA

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have a Jenkins job which requires a text file as Input parameter.I want to run the job multiple times with different files.I am hoping to do it through JAVA.Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a jenkins build from outside of jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517388/how-to-pass-file-to-jenkins-with-java This one worked for me.
Thanks!