# How to send a post request using groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to send a post request like get request, but I I'm getting server error 500, although I'm sure it works correctly.

Tell me how to send a post request with parameters via formdata?

My GET request:

```
url = 'http://logicased-mog.service.btlab.ru/alfresco/s/lecm/repository/api/getUploaderFolders?rootNode=alfresco://user/temp&generateDirectories=false'

def baseUrl = new URL(url)
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();

def authorization = 'user1:user1'
encodedBytes = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(authorization.getBytes()))
authorization = "Basic " + new String(encodedBytes);

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
connection.with {
    doOutput = true
    requestMethod = 'GET'
    resp = content.text
         }

connection.disconnect()
```

My POST request (doesn't work, error 500 is returned)

```
baseUrl = 'http://logicased-mog.service.btlab.ru/alfresco/s/api/upload?Alfresco-CSRFToken=null'
def data = [:]
    
def createUrl = new URL('http://logicased-mog.service.btlab.ru/alfresco/s/mog/outgoing/createOutgoing')
connection = (HttpURLConnection) createUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
connection.with {
    doOutput = true
    requestMethod = 'POST'
    nodeRef = resp
    fromSoo = 1
    attachments = []
    responseTo = resp
    signer = 'markinaaa'
    resp = content.text }
```

params nodeRef,fromSoo, attachments, responseTo  and signer I want to pass in the request body

Thanks!

Comment: use https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/ >> a standard way of sending requests in Groovy

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the content header like:
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")  ( or plan/text as with ur data type)

Comment: how can I pass the sheet?

Comment: Try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840277/how-to-make-http-call-with-file-in-groovy-to-upload-a-file-and-build-arguments